# Joining three tables on two different variables

Tags: sql, merge

I want to keep one unique CLIENT_ID record for each person, but pull in the first line (only one line) of data for each CLIENT_ID. For most CLIENT_IDs, there are about 20 rows of data, yet most of the variables I want to pull in will always match. For example, for CLIENT_ID 555 there are 20 rows of data but the STATE_CODE is the same in each of the 20 rows for CLIENT_ID 555. (I have read other posts about LEFT JOINs and why that doesn't easily work to pull in just one record but being a SQL novice, I'm not sure how to escape this?)

> However, there are some rows where the variables will be different in each of the 20 rows. For these variables, I just want to get total counts. For example, for VACCINE_TYPE, I want to count how many of the 20 rows are VACCINE_TYPE = COVID-19 for that CLIENT_ID (i.e., if 2 of the 20 rows under the variable name VACCINE_TYPE for CLIENT_ID 555 = COVID-19, then I want the column labeled COVID to say "2".

I also need to pull in STATE_CODE from the "Address" table.

> SELECT
> cl.CLIENT_ID,
> cl.FN,
> cl.FN,
> cl.BD,
> cl.BCN,
> addr.STATE_CODE,
>
> > > (SELECT COUNT (im.VACCINE_TYPE) from immune im where im.VACCINE_TYPE = 'COVID-19') as COVID
> > > from CLIENT cl
> > > left join IMMUNE im ON im.CLIENT_ID = cl.CLIENT_ID
> > > left join ADDRESS addr ON addr.ADDRESS_ID = cl.ADDRESS_ID
> > > WHERE addr.STATE_CODE='05'
> > > AND cl.BD between to_date('01/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY' AND to_date('12/31/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')
> > > AND ((cl.FN <> 'BBY' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%NB%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BB %' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BOY%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%GIRL%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BABY%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%UNKNOWN%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BBA %'
> > > AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BG %' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BGA %' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%PENDING%')
> > > AND cl.BCN IS NULL)
> > > OR (cl.BCN <> 'Null'
> > > AND (cl.FN <> 'BBY' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%NB%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BB %' AND cl.FIRST_NAME NOT LIKE '%BOY%'
> > > AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%GIRL%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BABY%' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%UNKNOWN%' AND cl.FIRST_NAME NOT LIKE '%BBA %' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BG %' AND cl.FN NOT LIKE '%BGA %' AND cl.FNE NOT LIKE '%PENDING%'))
> > > ORDER BY cl.FN

Comment: (i) In general, left/right joins help, when you want records listed, for which no dependent record exists. (ii) If you need to present something like your VACCINE_TYPE as column, your sub-select is a way to go - otherwise consider **GROUP BY**. (iii) Which version of which database system do you use?